# Converting object array into string es6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

How do i convert the following object array

```
let user =[
{key: "name", value: "xyz"},
{key: "friend", value: "abc"},
{key: "mobileno", value: "123"}];
```

into a string output such as

```
"name:xyz
friend:abc
mobileno:123"
```

so far i have done this

```
let person = [
{key: "name ",value: "harsh" },
{key: "friend ",value: "dhruvil" }, 
{key: "mobileno ",value: "982559061" }];

var str = JSON.stringify(person); 
var newstr = str.replace(/[^a-xyz]/g, ''); 
console.log(newstr);
```

Comment: If you have made any attempt yourself, please post your code you've tried.

Comment: you mean an object like `{name:xyz
friend:abc
mobileno:123}` ?

Comment: @GeorgeBailey nope, i meant just a string not object.

Comment: @DhruvilParel add your effort with question not in the comments so, people could point you in right direction\

Comment: Sorry about it, new to stackoverflow didn't knew how to do the formatting and layout @GeorgeBailey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first convert your array to the desired object using `.reduce` or whatever the way you like it for example

```
user.reduce((o, key) => Object.assign(o, {[key.key]: key.value}), {})
```

Now you can convert this object to string with `JSON.stringify` and then use `.replace` method on this string to replace the curly braces `{` with

```
replace(/[\{\}]/g, "")
```

```js
let user =[
{key: "name", value: "xyz", disabled: false},
{key: "friend", value: "abc ", disabled: true},
{key: "mobileno", value: "123", disabled: false}];

var x= user.reduce((o, key) => Object.assign(o, {[key.key]: key.value}), {});

console.log(JSON.stringify(x).replace(/[\{\}]/g, "").replace(/,/g, '\n'))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @George Bailey